# Ubuntu 16.04 never shuts down or reboots even in terminal

Tags: boot, command-line, shutdown

Usually, my Ubuntu 16.04 does not shutdown via GUI. So I tried it via terminal and it is still not working. The same happens for reboot, as the terminal only shows this message:

```
$sudo reboot now
Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and systemctl status reboot.target for details. 
$sudo shutdown now
Failed to start poweroff.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and systemctl status poweroff.target for details
```

In case it matters, my machine does not boot into grub first or any other boot manager. It just boots straight into Ubuntu everytime.

Comment: Please paste the results of `systemctl status reboot.target`. Also, don't use backticks for multiline pastes. Instead, either indent each line with four spaces or highlight the block and press the code block button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, but I had my problem fixed now by reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.